Spring authorization server RP-initiated logout not working
I have a project with spring gateway as oauth client for spring authorization server.
Everything is working fine in terms of oidc authentication besides the logout. Logout does not work due to CORS, as somehow after pressing the logout  button on the default spring logout page, the origin is null. If I add the "null" origin to allowed origins list, or disable cors, it works as expected.
Below is the configuration for spring gateway client:
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
    }

    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    private ServerLogoutSuccessHandler serverLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler successHandler = new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);
        successHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}/welcome");
        return successHandler;
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        String[] unprotectedPaths = new String[]{"/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/swagger-ui/**", "/actuator/**",
                "/oidc/**","/welcome/**", "/customer/registration", "/customer/registration-confirmation/**"};

        http.cors(withDefaults()).csrf(csrfSpec -> csrfSpec.csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                        .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new SpaServerCsrfTokenRequestHandler()))
                .authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec -> authorizeExchangeSpec.pathMatchers(unprotectedPaths).permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers("/notification/ws-connect").hasAuthority("SCOPE_notification.read")
                        .anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oAuth2ResourceServerSpec -> oAuth2ResourceServerSpec.jwt(withDefaults()))
                .logout(httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer -> httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.logoutSuccessHandler(serverLogoutSuccessHandler()));

        return http.build();
    }


    static final class SpaServerCsrfTokenRequestHandler extends ServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler {
        private final ServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler delegate = new XorServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();

        @Override
        public void handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Mono<CsrfToken> csrfToken) {
            // Always use XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler to provide BREACH protection of the CsrfToken when it is rendered in the response body.
            this.delegate.handle(exchange, csrfToken);
        }

        @Override
        public Mono<String> resolveCsrfTokenValue(ServerWebExchange exchange, CsrfToken csrfToken) {
            final var hasHeader = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get(csrfToken.getHeaderName()) != null;
            return hasHeader ? super.resolveCsrfTokenValue(exchange, csrfToken) : this.delegate.resolveCsrfTokenValue(exchange, csrfToken);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public WebFilter csrfCookieWebFilter() {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            exchange.getAttributeOrDefault(CsrfToken.class.getName(), Mono.empty()).subscribe(o -> ((CsrfToken) o).getToken());
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:63342"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}

Bellow is the api-gateway log:
2024-07-16T22:37:22.392+03:00 DEBUG 90681 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-6] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/logout', method=GET}
2024-07-16T22:37:22.392+03:00 DEBUG 90681 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-6] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/logout'
2024-07-16T22:37:22.392+03:00 DEBUG 90681 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-6] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : matched
2024-07-16T22:37:22.395+03:00 TRACE 90681 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-6] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [130c2a73-11] Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
2024-07-16T22:37:22.395+03:00 TRACE 90681 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-6] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : [130c2a73-5, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9990 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:63469] Handling completed
2024-07-16T22:37:37.036+03:00 TRACE 90681 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-6] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [130c2a73-12] HTTP POST "/logout", headers={masked}
2024-07-16T22:37:37.038+03:00 DEBUG 90681 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-6] o.s.w.c.reactive.DefaultCorsProcessor    : Reject: 'null' origin is not allowed
2024-07-16T22:37:37.038+03:00 TRACE 90681 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-6] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [130c2a73-12] Completed 403 FORBIDDEN, headers={masked}
2024-07-16T22:37:37.039+03:00 TRACE 90681 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-6] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : [130c2a73-6, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9990 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:63469] Handling completed

Later Edit:
It seems Chrome treats 2 different ports on localhost as same site. Also The JSESSIONID used by spring security is not SameSite, so it will be sent in cross origin request However, my original issue does not involve cross origin requests

Why are you adding CORS config? Shouldn't your SPA and gateway have the same origin to share the session cookie (required for oauth2Login and the TokenRelay filter to work)? Why are you configuring oauth2ResourceServer in a filter-chain already configured with oauth2Login? Security requirements are very different for the 2: need for sessions & CSRF protection, cookie-based VS token-based authorization, response status for unauthorized. requests,...

Also, after you call the Logout on the Spring client with OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler, if the Logout is successful, the response should be a redirection. What is this exact response (status and location)? How are you following this redirection?

The SPA and gateway will not have the same origin, not sure why you think they should. As long as the gateway is configured to allow the SPA origin, they can share the session cookie. Also I use oauth2ResourceServer just to access it from Postman with a bearer token. It won't stay like this as there is no reason to be both a client and a resource server. After pressing the logout button on the /logout page I get a 403

I tried both /logout from api-gateway(http://localhost:9990/logout) and from auth-server(http://localhost:9989/logout) and none of them logout and redirect. The auth server logout prints out the message that you have been logged out but there is no redirect happening

RP In RP-Initiated Logout stands for "Relying Party". This means that Logout starts from the client which closes its session and, if the operation is successful (found the session to close), redirects user agent to the OP (aka OpenID Provider or authorization server), so that the OP can terminate its own session for the logged out user. So Logout from the gateway and provide more DEBUG logs & redirection details.

"The SPA and gateway will not have the same origin, not sure why you think they should" as I already wrote, a session cookie should be flagged with same-site. CORS headers won't be enough for the browser to share this Spring cookie with other origins (services running on different ports). What you need is a reverse proxy, not CORS. WebPack one is just fine in dev. In any env, you can use the Gateway as proxy (to route to the SPA). You could also use a nginx instance or whatever ingress in front of both. A last option that works when SPA is packaged is to serve it from Gateway static assets.

I am using the gateway as a proxy, which should be fine from my understanding. Everything works fine besides the logout. I have other downstream services that receive all the info they need to operate. Also as a side note, you could have multiple clients and one gateway. The clients are not required to have the same origin.

How comes that the Logout requests lands with a null origin ? Wouldn't you be trying to send it with Postman instead of using an already authorized browser (one with an active session on the gateway)?

This is what is confusing for me also. For this test I do not use Postman, but the browser. Only thing I am doing is log in and then I go to api-gateway/logout where I get the logout confirmation page where I logout..that's it.

there is a similar issue posted here and apparently it will work fine once it is not deployed on local. For the time being, I will add "null" to the list of CORS allowed origins. I will also upgrade when there is a new version of spring security, as it seems to be spring issue, not a configuration one

You'll still have the same filter-chain configured as stateful (oauth2Login) and stateless (oauth2ResourceServer), with protection against CSRF required for some requests and useless for others, the need for different authorities mapping strategies, the need for different response status to unauthorized requests, ... What about trying to understand OAuth2 and the security benefits of keeping tokens on the server?

As I have already mentioned, the (oauth2ResourceServer) is for use with postman and it is temporary. As per my Oauth knowledge, this does not impact the logout whatsoever. If you think having the gateway as both client and resource server has any impact on the problem that I have described in the question, please explain. My question was very specific. I have already tried removing the resource sever configuration but it does not fix the issue.

I have also been explicit o'n what your question is missing for the us to understand your problem (exact request used to initiate the logout: what sends it, http verb, URL, payload). I've been explicit too on the fact that oauth2Login (and logout) are based on session and that a session cookie should be flagged with same site, reason for  the need of same origin instead of CORS for requests to your backend. Last, you don't need a cross origin request to the authorization server authorization endpoint. Setting the windows.location.href is just fine.

But as you seem to be hosting the authorization server too, you could put it behind the same reverse proxy as the gateway and your frontend, having the same origin for everything (no more CORS issue, CORS config, or hack to follow the authorization by setting the windows.location.href in Javascript instead of letting the browser follow the 302. This could even enable you to display login forms in an frame inside the frontend instead of leaving it).

Last Postman does not need to go through the gateway. It can send requests directly to resource server. If you really want it to go through the gateway (and develop with a different security conf than prod), define a second filter chain without oauth2Login and a second set of routes without the TokenRelay filter.

Apologies  if i misunderstand, but what you are saying is to change my architecture. That is not what I am looking for. I will have a SPA client(currently a web page that runs in Intellj HTTP server) that might not be deployed in the same domain as the gateway, hence CORS headers are needed. The backend services work fine as they do not need the session cookie, but only the token that comes via TokenRelay. The gateway works as a proxy. The backend services will be hidden from the outside world and accessed only via gateway, hence the postman situation.

I have added an example on https://github.com/ionutbarau/demo-stackoverflow. This was intended for a different question but can be used to reproduce the error. Just ignore the first part of the README and use steps 1-3 from How to use section. In order to reproduce the issue, just try to logout (point browser to localhost:9990/logout) after you've logged in. The login/logout pages are the default from spring security

"change my architecture. That is not what I am looking for." changing your architecture seems easier than changing the way session cookies are secured by browsers...

please try the example I posted and follow the exact steps to reproduce. There is no SPA involved when reproducing (there is no cross origin request involved). Also please post a section in the documentation, where it states that in order for RP initiated logout to work, both the SPA and oauth client need to be on the same domain. The session cookie will always be sent when a call will be made to the domain that issued it, regardless of who is sending it(that is how CSRF attacks take place). So it is should be fine to have an SPA on a different origin,through which you do POST to /logout.

"The session cookie will always be sent when a call will be made to the domain that issued it" That's wrong. Read about the SameSite flag for cookies. Session cookies should always be flagged SameSite (Spring ones are, check in your browser debugging tools). And I already wasted enough time here, bye.

RP-Initiated Logout (open the link and read the spec) starts after the logout was performed on the Relying Party (Spring app configured with oauth2Login). To initiate this 1st logout, a SPA should POST to the gateway /logout endpoint.
As any request to an app configured with oauth2Login, it is authorized with a session (the request must hold the session cookie). For this reason, the frontend sending this request must be served from the same host as the RP.
In the case of a SPA, the easiest option, by far, is to serve both the SPA and the BFF through the same reverse proxy (which can be the gateway itself). This removes cross origin requests between front and back ends. If the SPA is to be served from another domain than the API, then the BFF (gateway with oauth2Login and the TokenRelay filter) should be hosted on this other domain.
As any POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE request authorized with a session, it should be protected against CSRF (contain a CSRF token). In the case of a single-page app, this token is read from a cookie (with http-only false) and set as a header.
The answer to the POST request (after the gateway session is ended) should contain a Location header with an URI to end the session on the authorization server. If the origin from which the SPA is served (the reverse-proxy) is allowed on the authorization server, you can let the browser in which the SPA runs follow to this location. Otherwise, you might have to change the status of the gateway response from 302 to something in the 2xx range so that the Javascript code can observe the response, read the Location, and follow by setting the window.location.href (change the browser tab origin instead of sending a cross-origin request).
Detailed working sample (including logout) of spring-cloud-gateway used as OAuth2 BFF (with oauth2Login and the TokenRelay filter) for SPAs in this Baeldung article I wrote.

Apparently there is a good reason for having "null" Origin. Anybody interested can checkout this SO question for more information.
Basically if there is a redirect to another server during a CORS request, the Origin header will be changed to "null", as this is a privacy-sensitive context.
This happens in my situation, as doing a POST from the default spring logout page to the gateway /logout action makes it a CORS request.
During this request, a redirect to authorization server takes place, hence the browser sets the Origin header to null. Since I have CORS configured, the request gets rejected.
Initially I got confused, thinking that since I am not using the SPA for logout, there is no CORS involved.
What I wanted to achieve seems to not be feasible anymore.
The end goal was to have the SPA deployed on mydomain:80 and Gateway on mydomain:9990 (similar setup as localhost). This should work in theory, as they are same site but not same origin. This means that the Session cookie would be sent, but in order to make post request, CORS would need to be configured. I wanted to keep things simple (no proxy in front of both SPA and Gateway) but also did not want to bundle the SPA in the Gateway.
As a solution, I will need to rethink my setup and try to serve SPA via the gateway as @ch4mp proposed.

As mentioned in comments, you can use the gateway as a reverse proxy for the SPA: just define a route for it (without the TokenRelay filter which should be moved from the default filters to configuration of routes to resource servers).

Yes I did this and it worked. I will remove the TokenRelay filter also, but it seems to be working with it. Thanks for the help !

Yes, it works as soon as the route to the SPA is permitAll() . But. You can save a little reources: what serves the SPA assets does not need an access token. Also if using Actuator on the Gateway, you might want to secure its endpoints with a resource server filter-chain (distinct from the client one with oauth2Login, without sessions and used by clients on your backend like cluster monitor). So you might use this resource server filter-chain (or yet another one without security at all) and save resources used by sessions and the TokenRelay filter for request accessing the SPA assets.
